# When should I validate a form data in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Title is a bit ambiguous but here is the explanation:

I have email field in a form. WTF-Forms validate a proper email address and I can proceed after `validate_on_submit`.

If email is already taken in signup form for example, where should I check that? I can write a custom validator and fire validation error or I can proceed after validation and can flash error messages.

Which design is better. What are advantages, disadvantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either design *could* work, but I think it would make more sense to leave WTForm validation to validating the actual field.

For example, if you have an email field that gets the input of :

`notanemail`

This should throw a validation error because it is legitimately an error with validating the input in the field. This just makes more sense.

That same field with the input of `total@anemail.com` *is* valid, so the validation should continue and then you can do your check for an email address already being taken and flash an error.

It's all about separating the concerns. WTForms should only be used to validate that the user inputs valid information, not that it's a valid input to your database.

Comment: Yeah, I cannot decide while thinking about separating concerns. At first putting database check to a WTForms validation looks nicer but at the same time it feels like WTForms should just do input validation. Thats confusing.

Comment: It can be... But possible design pattern would be to hit an API endpoint once the form has been submitted. This would be so basically: 

if form.validate_on_submit():
    # Submit to API endpoint
else:
    # Flash error

Answer (score 0):

Check for valid syntax first, then check if it's already in use by someone else.  Checking for valid syntax is likely a much cheaper operation, so it's more efficient to start with that.

Also from a common sense standpoint, if the address is invalid, then presumably you wouldn't *care* if it were already in use (if that's even possible).

Comment: I am already doing that way. My problem is where I should put database check code. I can put database check to view (or route) or inside form class. I cannot decide.